ArcGIS Online Experience Builder - swipe widget to display name of map currently selected
am using the Swipe widget in ArcGIS Experience Builder to swipe between 2 different maps.  I am wondering whether a text box could be displayed on the maps with dynamic text which would give the name of the map which is currently being shown with the swipe widget?

that could maybe work with dynamic text referring to either the map in the foreground or the background? Or you could work with popups from both maps?

yes. Something like dynamic text or a pop-up that would appear on a fixed place in the map window which would tell the user which map had been selected.  I was wondering whether there is a text box in a fixed place on the map which would be in a fixed place, independent of a location, which would not move when the map was either scrolled or zoomed in/out.
